# Conditional drop-down list from single table

Tags: excel

It is fairly simple to populate a drop-down list from a fixed table of names (here 'Name1') using data validation.

[image]

Is it possible to populate a second drop-down list from a second, unnormalised table, akin to doing a lookup on the range with the input value being the selection from the first drop-down list?

[image]

e.g. Selecting 'A' from the first drop-down means only 'D', 'E' and 'F' are available in the second drop-down.

Unfortunately, the second table cannot be split out into tables 'A', 'B' and 'C' as there are plenty of tutorials explaining how to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following link, it describes a complex drop down pretty well and includes a nice little video tutorial http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html

Comment: As said in the last paragraph, the second table cannot be split out into multiple named tables. This tutorial relies on this possibility.